# alter table add partition using a procedure oracle g11

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, database-partitioning

1. I'm trying to add partitions by month on a partitioned table using a procedure that will be ran each year on January 1.

   ```
   create or replace procedure create_partitions as
     part VARCHAR2(50);
     date_val DATE;
     sql_val VARCHAR2(4000);
   begin
     date_val := TO_DATE(CONCAT(extract(year from sysdate),'-06-01 00:00:00'),'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN');
     part := CONCAT('P_MAY',extract(year from sysdate));
     sql_val := 'ALTER TABLE TEST1 
       ADD PARTITION '||part||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||date_val||')
       SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_val;
   end create_partitions;
   ```

When I run this procedure I get this error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Instead of concatenating I tried with binding values

```
sql_val := 'ALTER TABLE TEST1 
    ADD PARTITION :1 VALUES LESS THAN (:2)
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_val USING part, date_val;
```

and I get this

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

If I try this with hardcoded values it work without problem. But I need something dynamic.

2. also there is a way to add multiple partitions in G11 without running multiple alter queries? I tried this, but I think it works only in G12+

   ```
   ALTER TABLE TEST1 ADD
     PARTITION t1...
     PARTITION t2...
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your date value into date literal like this:

```
date_val := TO_DATE(CONCAT(extract(year from sysdate),'-06-01 00:00:00'),'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN');
date_str := 'DATE'''||to_char(date_val, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||'''';
part := CONCAT('P_MAY',extract(year from sysdate));
  sql_val := 'ALTER TABLE TEST1 
    ADD PARTITION '||part||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||date_str||')
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_val;
```

Or if you need time component (but I see you don't in your example) like that:

```
date_str := 'TO_DATE('''||to_char(date_val, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')||''', ''yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'')';
```

I can also recommend to download PL/SQL utilities packages from http://www.softcraftltd.co.uk/downloads/

Comment: wow. thanks! It really works. And for my 2nd question, there is a way in G11 to add multiple partitions in just one 'alter table'?

Comment: No. This option is available only with 12c. Please mark you question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

this is how your seq should be:

```
sql_val := 'ALTER TABLE TEST1 
    ADD PARTITION '||' '||part|| ' ' ||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||date_str||')
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE';
```

you need a blankd space where the partition name is